# Why isn't Safari 3.1 showing my alerts

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm trying to debug a problem that happens on Safari 3.1 (but not in 3.2 or later, nor in any other browser, and yes, I've tried to close this is "upgrade your browser", but the client won't allow it).  So I've thrown a bunch of `alert('doing foo');` statements in my javascript file, but none of them are showing up.  I can type an alert command in the console and it does show up.  So why are the alerts in the code not showing up?

Also, any general hints on how do debug javascript in such an ancient browser would be appreciated.

And to answer the questions below - I put some of those alerts in code that I know is executing because it's doing the right thing.  And I turned off cache in the browser Developer menu.

Comment: Can you post the code (or a demo page)? This seems really odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are not clearing your cache or your code is throwing an error before it hits any of the alert statements.

Comment: I've turned off caching in the Developer menu, and there are no errors in the error console.

Comment: Turns out the "Disable caches" in the developer menu doesn't work - you have to empty the cache in the Edit menu.

Answer (score 0):

Because the code that contains the `alert()` calls is not executing.  Without more info it's hard to help more, but check the JS console for any reported errors that may have prematurely halted execution.

Comment: How do you know for sure?  Also, maybe try `console.log('doing foo')` instead. But I can't imagine that this would work an alert doesn't.

Comment: The code is executing because it's doing some of the things it's supposed to be doing.  It's just not doing other things.